# Tell me how to put the GridView in the ListView (I'm having a lot of trouble creating the adapter)

Tags: android, listview, gridview, adapter, android-adapter

[This is the design I want to implement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqUav.jpg)

Now that I'm in progress, I have completed the customization of the adapter(extends ArrayAdapater(Site)) that connects the gridView to the item in the GridView. The items in the gridview items I use are contained in an array called ArrayList(Site), and an object named Site contains one String variable (site's name), one Url (url of the site), one int variable image resource). I have three types of gridView that contain multiple site information. So what I want to do is to put each Gridview as an item in the ListView. If you put the name of each type of GridView in the title of each ListView and click the corresponding title, you will see that the corresponding GridView is displayed.
So what I want to know is how to create an Adapter that uses the ArrayListAdapter that I use to link the GridView with the custom adapter to the ListView item again.

I would be grateful if you could advise me about the options I tried but failed.
I would also appreciate if you can let me know what type of adapter you need to customize.

[How I tried and failed]

1] Using ExpandableList and ExpandableListAdapter

- I have tried several times, and when I pressed List, it came out to the ListView design, not the GridView design, and the GridView itself was embedded several times in it.

2] Making ExpandableGridView

- I have been browsing several times and found out that the ExpandableGridView created by some people was the design I wanted. So I tried to customize it to my code but it failed to understand the original code. (I'm a beginner to start Android programming ...)

3] Making my own Adapter(extends SimpleAdapter)

- The data that I need to connect to the ListView is a String variable(the name of each gridview), and ArrayList(Site) that contain data of each items in GridView. So I created a Hashtable that informs an Arraylist(Site) containing the items of the GridView corresponding to the String variable as the key. So I looked up several adapters and found that SimpleAdapter was using HashMap as data and tried to customize it, but it failed.

If you have the information you need about my code, I will post it right away.

I want to know how to make it as easy as possible...

Comment: I'm not sure that adapter inside another adapter is a good way. You can try to pass  3 rows as a single row, and use a `TableLayout` with a `TableRow` to display this in a single line.

Comment: If I use tablelayout, can I make the original obscured Gridview appear below it when I press tablerow?

Comment: I mean use this with `ExpandableListView` or `RecyclerView`. `GridView` has no expandable rows by default, and I didn't hear about `ExpandableGridView`, but you can try.